# Is there a windicss equivalent for "peer-{modifier} in tailwind"

Tags: windicss

Is there a windicss equivalent to tailwind's 'peer-{modifier}' that you can use to style and element base on a sibling elements' state.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [:sibbling](https://windicss.org/utilities/general/variants.html#child-selectors) to achieve the same effect as peer-[]